# Jquery window load not working via ajax

Tags: jquery

I'm updating result via ajax.

```
$.ajax({
  url:"b.html",
  success:function(data){
   $('#result').html(data);
  }
});
```

In my b.html

```
<div>
.
.
.
</div>
<script type="text/javavascript">
  $(window).load(alert('a'));
</script>
```

I'm not getting any alert popup box. I need to run this javascript after the entire page has loaded.
Please help me to get out of this?.

Comment: maybe there is an error, try adding an error callback function

Comment: "<script type="text/javavascript">" - Check the text here and also you cannot trigger alert or console.log. Better to use inside to success function.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>

</div>
<script type="text/javavascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){


    $.ajax({
      url:"b.html",
      success:function(data){
       $('#result').html(data);
       alert('a')
      }
    });


    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you are missing the function in the load method:

```
$(window).load(function(){
     alert('a')
});
```

but this won't fire alert because you are using ajax and page does not get loaded, only the div.

So you can try in the success function like this:

```
success:function(data){
   $('#result').html(data, function(){ alert('This alerts') });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this at b.html

```
$('document').ready(function () {
   alert('a');
});
```

Comment: b.html not loaded directly from browser window, it is ajax request.